# map method iteration in stepper for material ui

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, redux, material-ui

- I am trying to add the redux form inside my stepper.
- but the problem is if I add form fields inside   its reflecting in all the three places.
- so I started debugging the stepper code.
- found that they are iterating in map method.
- so I thought on basis of putting if condition for label I will show the div and form tags.
- but its not working.
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- so that in future I will fix it myself.
- providing my code snippet and sandbox below

https://codesandbox.io/s/y2kjpl343z

```
return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Stepper activeStep={activeStep} orientation="vertical">
          {steps.map((label, index) => {
            console.log("steps---->", steps);
            console.log("label---->", label);
            console.log("index---->", index);

            // if (index === 0) {
            if (label === "Select campaign settings") {
              return (
                <Step key={label}>
                  <StepLabel>{label}</StepLabel>
                  <StepContent>
                    <Typography>{getStepContent(index)}</Typography>
                    <div className={classes.actionsContainer}>
                      <div>
                        <div>test1</div>

                        <form>here</form>

                        <Button
                          disabled={activeStep === 0}
                          onClick={this.handleBack}
                          className={classes.button}
                        >
                          Back
                        </Button>
                        <Button
                          variant="contained"
                          color="primary"
                          onClick={this.handleNext}
                          className={classes.button}
                        >
                          {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? "Finish" : "Next"}
                        </Button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </StepContent>
                </Step>
              );
            }

            if (label === "Create an ad group") {
              return (
                <Step key={label}>
                  <StepLabel>{label}</StepLabel>
                  <StepContent>
                    <Typography>{getStepContent(index)}</Typography>
                    <div className={classes.actionsContainer}>
                      <div>
                        <div>test1</div>

                        <form>here</form>

                        <Button
                          disabled={activeStep === 0}
                          onClick={this.handleBack}
                          className={classes.button}
                        >
                          Back
                        </Button>
                        <Button
                          variant="contained"
                          color="primary"
                          onClick={this.handleNext}
                          className={classes.button}
                        >
                          {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? "Finish" : "Next"}
                        </Button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </StepContent>
                </Step>
              );
            }

            // return (
            //   <Step key={label}>
            //     <StepLabel>{label}</StepLabel>
            //     <StepContent>
            //       <Typography>{getStepContent(index)}</Typography>
            //       <div className={classes.actionsContainer}>
            //         <div>
            //           <div>test1</div>

            //           <form>here</form>

            //           <Button
            //             disabled={activeStep === 0}
            //             onClick={this.handleBack}
            //             className={classes.button}
            //           >
            //             Back
            //           </Button>
            //           <Button
            //             variant="contained"
            //             color="primary"
            //             onClick={this.handleNext}
            //             className={classes.button}
            //           >
            //             {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? "Finish" : "Next"}
            //           </Button>
            //         </div>
            //       </div>
            //     </StepContent>
            //   </Step>
            // );
          })}
        </Stepper>
        {activeStep === steps.length && (
          <Paper square elevation={0} className={classes.resetContainer}>
            <Typography>All steps completed - you&apos;re finished</Typography>
            <Button onClick={this.handleReset} className={classes.button}>
              Reset
            </Button>
          </Paper>
        )}
      </div>
    );
```

Comment: Do you mind a a refactor? I think you are missing some concepts of React :) I'm working on this sandbox, when I'm ready I'll post an answer ok?

Comment: @0xc14m1z hey thanks for reply, can you give comments to your changes it will help me to learn

Comment: Of course, I need a few more minutes to test everything, when I'll be done I'll ask you to check whether it works as you are expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/6l3wpo3xyr

To me, it seems that is working properly and with clear code. It can be done a bit better but to start with, it may be ok.

I can edit the answer to add details if needed.

#### Answer for comment about `Object.entries`

As an instance variable for the component I declared:

```
steps = {
  "Select campaign settings": Step1,
  "Create an ad group": Step2,
  "Create an ad": Step3
};
```

This is just a Plain Javascript Object. In ES6 the `Object` class has the entries method that, taken an object like this one, returns an array an array of key and values of the given object. In this case:

```
Object.entries(steps)

[
  [ "Select campaign settings", Step1 ],
  [ "Create an ad group", Step2 ],
  [ "Create an ad", Step3 ]
]
```

Having such a structure, it's easier to map through the key-value pairs with `map`. The first argument of the `map` method of the `Array` class is the current element of the array. Having used `Object.entries` earlier, the element is the single array that represents a key-pair:

```
Object.entries(steps)[0]  // [ "Select campaign settings", Step1 ]
```

#### Answer for comment about `.map(([ label, CustomStep ]) => ...`

This is just a common use of the `Array.map` method. Generally, it allows to transform an array into another using a mapping function. A function that takes an element of the array and return another thing.

In this case, the element of the array to cycle is the key-value pair provided by the `Object.entries` call. With ES6 arrays, as well as objects, can be destructured, and that is what is happening there:

```
// you may see something like this around:
.map(element => {
  // let's say that element is an array, you'll use it like:
  // element[0] is the first element
  // element[1] is the second one
})

// with ES6 that array can be destructed on-the-fly this way, which is totally equivalent
.map(([ label, CustomStep ]) => {
  // label is the index 0 (element[0])
  // CustomStep is the index 1 (element[1])
})
```

Comment: hey can you update comments its hard to understand :(

Comment: What do you need in particular? Feel free to ask :) Then, does it work how it should?

Comment: hey can you tell me why you used Object.entries in the code changes, if you give comments that would be great :(

Comment: I added an explanation about the usage of `Object.entries` here.

Comment: thanks now I understood little bit, can you tell how your mapping, if you give some more details that would be great....specifically this line map(([label, CustomStep])

Comment: I added an explanation about the "map line"

Comment: hey but why we are using specifically map method, using for loop can we achieve it and what does destructured mean...sorry for late response