# Cannot read property 'getState' of undefined error

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, material-ui

- I am trying to add the react sticky header to my stepper.
- but the problem is if I add inside my App.js its not rendering.
- so I started debugging the App.js code.
- if I give console inside my render method of App.js its not displaying     console.log("App---->");
- right now I am getting Cannot read property 'getState' of undefined error
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- so that in future I will fix it myself.
- providing my code snippet and sandbox below

https://codesandbox.io/s/6zv5n0ro9z

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { StickyContainer, Sticky } from "react-sticky";
// ...

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log("App---->");
    return (
      <StickyContainer>
        {/* Other elements can be in between `StickyContainer` and `Sticky`,
        but certain styles can break the positioning logic used. */}
        <Sticky>
          {({
            style,

            // the following are also available but unused in this example
            isSticky,
            wasSticky,
            distanceFromTop,
            distanceFromBottom,
            calculatedHeight
          }) => <header style={style}>{/* ... */}</header>}
        </Sticky>
        {/* ... */}
      </StickyContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
//import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Demo from "./demo";
import App from "./components/App";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { logger } from "redux-logger";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
//import reducer from "./reducers";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

//const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk, logger));

//ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.querySelector("#root"));

render(
  //     <Provider store={store}>
  <Provider>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to either pass a `store` to the `Provider` as Mark suggests, or if you have simplified your example to the point of not needing it, then remove the `Provider` element entirely, so you are just rendering the `App` element. The current stack trace shows that the error is in `Provider`.

You also need to add:

```
export default App;
```

at the bottom of App.js.

Comment: I made the code changes as per your suggestions but still its not working...its so confusing can you update in sandbox...providing my updated code...https://codesandbox.io/s/6zv5n0ro9z

Comment: You are missing a comma as the error message `SyntaxError
/index.js: Unexpected token, expected , (22:2)` indicates.

Comment: thanks Ryan...can you help me with this one too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54116709/map-method-iteration-in-stepper-for-material-ui

Answer (score 8):

You need to pass your store as props to the wrapping Provider

```
render(<Provider store={store} >
          <App />
       </Provider>,document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 7):

Chances are that you would have not set the store property correctly.

Make sure that store is imported this way.

```js
import store from './store';
```

and not the below way

import {store}  from './store';

```js
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```
 import store from './store';
```

Running code should look like below

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './routes/App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from './store';

ReactDOM.render(
  
    <Provider store={store}>
      <React.StrictMode> 
      <App />
      </React.StrictMode>
    </Provider>,

  document.getElementById('root')
);

 
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're going to render a React-Redux `<Provider>`, you *must* create a Redux store and pass it as a prop named `store`.  I see you've got those lines in there - you should uncomment them.

Comment: I made the code changes  but still its not working...its so confusing can you update in sandbox...providing my updated code...https://codesandbox.io/s/6zv5n0ro9z

Comment: thanks ...can you help me with this one too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54116709/map-method-iteration-in-stepper-for-material-ui

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else stumbling on this, try to pull your `<Provider>` up a level and make use of your getters from a child.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have imported `import store from './redux/store'` and pasing provider as  `<Provider store={store}>` here I am emphasizing on `store' file and import must be small letter must not be camel or uppercase. This is what i have found during redux learning.

Answer (score 1):

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './routes/App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from './store';

ReactDOM.render(
  
    <Provider store={store}>
      <React.StrictMode> 
      <App />
      </React.StrictMode>
    </Provider>,

  document.getElementById('root')
);

 
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).