# rendering two different components in react way

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, material-ui

- I am trying to add the react sticky header to my stepper.
- if I try to render bot the components together I am getting an error.
- so I debugged and rendering separately.
- when I render separately I am not facing an error. store is not defined
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- so that in future I will fix it myself.
- providing my code snippet and sandbox below

https://codesandbox.io/s/y2kjpl343z

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Demo from "./demo";
import App from "./components/App";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'


// const store = createStore(
//   reducer,
//   applyMiddleware(thunk, logger)
// )

//ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.querySelector("#root"));

render(
       <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
    <Demo />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: `if I try to render bot the components together I am getting an error.` what's the error?

Comment: @NicholasTower `store is not defined`

Comment: @Treycos That's fixed by adding `import store from './store';`. I was wondering about the first error though.

Comment: I was just citing the error given in his question. Well, creating a store is a little bit more complicated than that (see the answers below)

Comment: Thanks. i was wondering about the first error though, when they were rendering both components. EDIT: on rereading the question, maybe that was the error both times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define a redux store to pass down to the `Provider` component.

To define a store, you need to have at least a reducer, I am going to create a fake one now, you'll create your own later:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Demo from "./demo";
import App from "./components/App";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

import { createStore } from 'redux'

const reducer = () => ({})
const store = createStore(reducer)

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
    <Demo />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

### Update after your comment

If you don't need to use redux, just use a `div`, or better, a `Fragment`:

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Demo from "./demo";
import App from "./components/App";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Fragment>
    <App />
    <Demo />
  </Fragment>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: @Treycos: hey thanks for your reply...it worked but without using redux can you tell me how to render two different components

Comment: hey can you help me with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54116709/map-method-iteration-in-stepper-for-material-ui

Comment: Sure, I am going to check it

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't create a store using the redux function : [`createStore`](https://redux.js.org/api/createstore). Before being able to use redux, you first need to create a reducer to give to your `Provider`.

Example from the documentation :

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'

function todos(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO':
      return state.concat([action.text])
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const store = createStore(todos, ['Use Redux'])

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
    <Demo />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: hey thanks for your reply...it worked but without using redux can you tell me how to render two different components

Comment: What do you mean by without redux ? Well, simply put something in the render function of your `App` component

Comment: hey can you help me with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54116709/map-method-iteration-in-stepper-for-material-ui

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a store variable to the Provider component, but never define it.
Create new file:

```
import {createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  // You can fill here all the states that you want
})

export const store = 
createStore(  
  rootReducer,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk), window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f)
);
```

Now import the file to your **index.js**

> import store from './store';

Comment: @Treycos: hey thanks for your reply...it worked but without using redux can you tell me how to render two different components

Comment: hey can you help me with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54116709/map-method-iteration-in-stepper-for-material-ui